# Pandas convert boolean column to column name when true

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with boolean values (well int values that are either 0 or 1, but that's not important right now):

```
A B C D
0 0 1 0
1 0 0 0
0 1 1 1
1 0 0 1
```

And I want to convert it so that "1" (True) values are converted to the header name of the column and 0 values to NaN. The resulting df needs not have a header.
Expected output:

```
NaN NaN C   NaN
A   NaN NaN NaN
NaN B   C   D
A   NaN NaN D
```

Iterating over the rows and assigning those values with a check could work, but is there no faster/more pandas-idiomatic way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with `DataFrame` constructor and no columns parameter if performance is important:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df == 1, df.columns, np.nan))
print (df)
     0    1    2    3
0  NaN  NaN    C  NaN
1    A  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN    B    C    D
3    A  NaN  NaN    D
```

And if need output in file with no columns and index values add `index=False` and `header=None` to [`DataFrame.to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
df.to_csv('file.csv', index=False, header=None)
```

EDIT:

If performance is important, you can avoid `apply` because loops under the hood. Here for the most vectorized and fastest solution is best use `np.where`:

```
#[40000 rows x 40 columns]
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)
df = pd.concat([df] * 10, ignore_index=True, axis=1)


In [180]: %%timeit
     ...: for i in df.columns:
     ...:     df[i] = df[i].apply(lambda x: i if x==1 else np.nan)
     ...:     
690 ms ± 13.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [181]: %%timeit
     ...: df.apply(lambda s: [s.name if v == 1 else np.nan for v in s])
     ...: 
680 ms ± 23 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [182]: %%timeit
     ...: pd.DataFrame(np.where(df == 1, df.columns, np.nan))
     ...: 
42.7 ms ± 3.26 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [183]: %%timeit
     ...: df.T.where(df.T != 1, df.columns).T.where(df != 0, np.nan)
     ...: 
17 s ± 644 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 2):

With numpy where

```
np.where(df == 1, df.columns, np.nan)

array([[nan, nan, 'C', nan],
       ['A', nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, 'B', 'C', 'D'],
       ['A', nan, nan, 'D']], dtype=object)
```

---

How to convert np.array to pd.DataFrame (added by @jezrael)

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df == 1, df.columns, np.nan), columns=df.columns)
print (df)
     A    B    C    D
0  NaN  NaN    C  NaN
1    A  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN    B    C    D
3    A  NaN  NaN    D
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something with [DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```py
df.apply(lambda s: [s.name if v == 1 else np.nan for v in s])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
for i in df.columns:
    df[i] = df[i].apply(lambda x: i if x==1 else np.nan)
df.columns = [''] * len(df.columns)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use np.where or pd.mask like below

```py
np.where(df.values==1, df.columns, np.nan)

## or
df.mask(df==1,df.columns)
```

Comment: do you test `df.mask(df==1,df.columns)` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `where` from `pandas`:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html)

Note that `T` is important to have proper result.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0,1,0,1],
                   'B': [0,0,1,0],
                   'C': [1,0,1,0],
                   'D': [0,0,1,1]
                   })


df = df.T.where(df.T != 1, df.columns).T.where(df != 0, np.nan)
```

Output:

```
     A    B    C    D
0  NaN  NaN    C  NaN
1    A  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN    B    C    D
3    A  NaN  NaN    D
```